# What's wrong with my cat command?

Tags: files, cat

I lent a friend a computer with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it, and he messed up the `cat` command.

```
$ cat testfile.txt
cat: meow!
$
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this? please?

Output of `which cat`:

```
/bin/cat
```

Comment: Try `which cat`. If it says something like "siamese" or other cat's species, you friend is a genius. Otherwise, copy the output in your question.

Comment: April fools! Lolz

Comment: What are the contents of `testfile.txt`?

Comment: @Mateo `testing..`. nano works fine!

Comment: Please add the results of `file /bin/cat` and `ls -l /bin/cat*`. By the way, your "friend" had root access, doesn't he?

Comment: Ah... he did have root access. I checked the file contents: `echo "cat: meow"`

Comment: I didn't expect a question with this title on *this* SE site ... ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If he's a **friend**, he probably did something of the style (as root)(1):

```
mv /bin/cat /bin/cat.orig 
echo "echo 'cat: meow! '" > /bin/cat
chmod 755 /bin/cat
```

If he's less of a friend, he omitted the first line.

Asking `apt-file`

```
apt-file search -F /bin/cat
```

says that the package is `coreutils`. You can probably reinstall it, although I see it as a bit of a dangerous thing...

(1) well, I really would have added `alias which="echo cat: is a siamese"` to your .bashrc, but well...

Comment: *If he's less of a friend, he omitted the first line.* I like the way you said that.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually an April Fool's trick. I changed the clock on my Debian box out of April 1st, and it fixed itself. Sick, sick joke...

Comment: I changed my date to April 1st and tested it on Ubuntu 12.04, no jokes here.

Comment: My `cat` commands are normal today again... Weird, but that's what I found out to fix it :-S