# Why do I get a train when I run 'ls'?

Tags: command-line, ls, animations

I have recently noticed something odd that I don't like very much:

[image: When running ls I get a train]

So why am I getting a train upon running `ls`? And how can I stop this and make it behave normally? Is this an Easter Egg that I have discovered? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

**Information Update:**

Running `which ls` gets me the same train, and running `ls -l $(which ls)` just gets me another type of train.

Running `command -v ls` outputs nothing. And running `command -v sl` also outputs nothing.

This may all have something to do with the `cow` (or something like that) package that I recently installed that promised to 'lighten things up a little'.

Comment: Perhaps someone aliased your `ls` to `sl`?

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232/unix-linux-pranks

Comment: And now we know why you wanted to convert a MP4 to an animated GIF earlier. I install `sl` by default just to have a chuckle when I fat finger something. You'll probably have to unalias this if you didn't do this yourself just to get a good chuckle.

Comment: That's similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/441701/whats-wrong-with-my-cat-command ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Try to remove the funny package via

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge sl
   ```
2. Check your aliases for `ls` e.g. in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.
3. Check the binary `/usr/games/sl` and delete

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/games/sl
   ```
4. Check the output of

   ```
   strace sl |& grep execve
   strace ls |& grep execve
   ```

   if point three has no success.
5. And in future, do NOT install anything that promises to 'lighten things up a little' in the description. **;)**

Answer (score 18):

Generally, you can prepend \ to a command to disable aliasing only for that instance of the command run.
E.g.,

```
[2023]$ alias ls
alias ls='ls -F -Chs --color=tty'
[2024]$ ls
total 140K
4.0K bin/           0 Downloads@           0 prog.git@
...

[2025]$ \ls
bin  Downloads     doc.git  freertos.git  prog.git  tmp
...
```

So, I recommend trying your ls with  a prepended '\'

Next, you can try running the ls command directly with full path.

```
/bin/ls
```

Next,
command /bin/ls

also, check your path,

```
echo $PATH
make sure that /bin is the first entry.
$PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

But, I believe that removing `cow` would help.